# How can I get awk to ignore newlines in data?

Tags: awk, delimiter, csv

I regularly have to manipulate messy text data that I need to break into fields.

I have had good experience using the backspace (008 decimal) as a field separator and delete (decimal 127) as record separator since those never appear in typed files.

I can get a program to split everything the way I want, but I want to use awk too. It accepts `RS=<delete>` but it also breaks records on newline which I don't want.

Obviously, I can replace newlines with some sort of sequence and flip it back, but is there a slicker way to do this?

Comment: Add example input and desired result please. Too much work to guess.

Comment: Don't answer questions you don't understand. I'm using backspace and delete characters as delimiters because they don't appear in hand entered data files. For a simple test, try the following:

cat > test
a<BACKSPACE>b<BACKSPACE>c<DELETE>
d<BACKSPACE>e<BACKSPACE>f<DELETE>
g<BACKSPACE>h<BACKSPACE>i<DELETE>

This creates three records with 3 fields each -- the last field should contain a newline. But if you try

awk '{FS="\010"}{RS="\177"}{OFS=" "}{ORS="\n"}{print NR"--"NF"--"$0}' test

I guarantee that's not what you'll see.

Comment: @jas, awk won't break on newline if set to most normal characters. But this isn't normal. I recommend testing behavior or doing research before telling people that what they're observing isn't happening.

Comment: My apologies --- comment deleted. I should have asked for more clarification; I see now I didn't fully understand the issue. Let's see what others can come up with.

Comment: What version of `awk`? If `gawk` you can set `FS` and `RS` to regex's. You set a regex that cannot happen such as `RS=FS="X^"` and the whole file is read and `$1` is the whole file. Is this what you mean? Your question is not clear without example input and output.

Comment: It's GNU Awk 3.1.7. I have many GB of unstructured data to analyze that can contain any typeable/pastable character. Breaking things into fields and records simplifies analysis and single character delimiters increases the number of tools I can use. So I want to use backspace and delete as delimiters since they work great with cut, tr, sed, and other tools. I can use any sequence I want with awk except backspace, arrows, and delete . I know many ways to cut this data. I'm looking for tricks that allow me to seach/modify huge amounts of data quickly with a minimum number of steps.

Comment: I really don't understand what you're asking for help with (add concise, testable sample input and expected output to your question) but wrt the script you posted in a comment: `awk '{FS="\010"}{RS="\177"}{OFS=" "}{ORS="\n"}{print NR"--"NF"--"$0}' test` - that is setting `RS` and `FS` **after** the first line has been read and split into fields using the default RS/FS values. The correct syntax for what you appear to be trying to do is `awk 'BEGIN{FS="\010"; RS="\177"} {print NR"--"NF"--"$0}' test` but note that is gawk-specific due to multi-char RS. Those ORS/OFS values were the defaults.

Comment: I see what's going on. Those weren't supposed to be interpreted as multicharacter separators -- they were meant as single character octal codes based on https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Escape-Sequences.html but they're not being interpreted that way . My syntax is no good. For example, I want a file consisting of the line: "a<BS>b<BS>c<DEL>c<BS>d" to be interpreted as two records with the first one having 3 fields and the second having two. I'm just subbing backspaces for some other character such as tab and the delete code where you'd normally have a newline

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this works as you expect IF you set the RS and FS as needed.

Given:

```
$ echo -n $'a\bb\bc\177c\bd' | od -c
0000000    a  \b   b  \b   c 177   c  \b   d                            
0000011
```

You can use `gawk` this way:

```
$ echo -n $'a\bb\bc\177c\bd' | awk -v FS=$'\b' -v RS=$'\177' '{ print NR, NF, $1, $2, $3}'
1 3 a b c
2 2 c d
```

Obviously the `\b` would cause the print of `$0` to not show correctly, but the record count, field count, and individual fields are as expected.

Note the Bashism of `$'[string or character]'` to set both the test string to create the single character `RS` and `FS` awk variables.

Comment: Thanks -- this is exactly what I needed. The bashism was what I was missing. 

Catting out files containing backspaces, deletes, arrows, and the like is weird as one would expect, but being able to use characters I know can't be in the file without having to scan first is nice

Answer (score 0):

I just want to point out that the ideal characters to use (instead of backspace and delete) are the characters:

INFORMATION SEPARATOR 1 (UNIT SEPARATOR): \x1F (decimal 031) aka U+001F

INFORMATION SEPARATOR 2 (RECORD SEPARATOR): \x1E (decimal 030) aka U+001E

This is exactly what these characters were designed for, though almost no one uses them. They are extremely unlikely to appear in text data.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).